# ViewPager cannot cast from source type to destination type

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, xamarin, android-resources

In Xamarin, I am coding a ViewPager application and am getting this error:

> Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

At this line of code:

`ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) FindViewById(Resource.Id.viewPager);`

Here is my activity_main.axml layout file with the reference to the ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

May I have some help with this please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's incorrect for monodroid, use this one instead:

```
ViewPager pager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPager);
```